# How to see how many free users you have in a Google Apps for Business account

Tags: google-workspace

Is there a way to tell how many free users you have in a Google Apps for Business account? In other words, if you had 1st gen account that allowed for 100 free users is there a way to tell that you have a first gen account with 100 places, rather than the later accounts that had 50, then 25, then 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer myself. If you go to this URL:

```
https://admin.google.com/EXAMPLE.COM/AdminHome#DomainSettings/subtab=subscriptions&notab=1
```

and replace the EXAMPLE.COM with your Google apps for business URL it will tell you.